# Matplotlib Plot Difference Between Two Unsorted Value Series

Tags: data-visualization, python, matplotlib

I am trying to figure out how to plot the following in Matplotlib.

Suppose I have a sample of 1000 random operations. There are two ways to perform each operation: a new way and an old way. My data consists of the name of each operation as the first column, followed by the time it takes to perform this operation using the new way, followed by another column containing the time that it takes to perform it using the new way.

Something like this:

`| Operation Name | Time (New Way) | Time (Old Way) |`

`|     ...        |        ...     |      ...       |`

My question is two-fold. First is what are some typical ways to demonstrate the difference between the New Way and the Old Way? These quantities may differ in value by up to five orders of magnitude (logarithmic plot?), but more often by 2-3 orders of magnitude.

The second part is how would one actually do it in Matplotlib? That is, I am not sure what would be the more optimal way to sort the data from shortest time to longest time as that seems to give a better illustration. Also, I am struggling to choose the best type of plot, based on the available examples.

Any advice or help is appreciated.